# Set Variable Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm sure this is something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Why doesn't this code work?

```
DECLARE @FirstSaturday DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME

SELECT @FirstSaturday = min(RED1.DATE)
FROM REDFRIDAYDATES..TBLREDFRIDAYALLDATES RED1
WHERE Period = 9 AND year = 2009
SELECT CASE
WHEN getdate() < @FirstSaturday
THEN  set @ENDDATE = getdate()
ELSE  SET @enddate = @FirstSaturday


END
```

I simply want the value of the earlier date, today or the end of the period, to be assigned to @enddate.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I am using SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT CASE` just doesn make any sense, try:-

```
DECLARE @FirstSaturday DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME

SELECT @FirstSaturday = min(RED1.DATE)
FROM REDFRIDAYDATES..TBLREDFRIDAYALLDATES RED1
WHERE Period = 9 AND year = 2009

SELECT @ENDDATE = CASE
WHEN getdate() < @FirstSaturday
THEN  getdate()
ELSE  @FirstSaturday
END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @enddate = CASE
WHEN getdate() < @FirstSaturday THEN  getdate()
ELSE  @FirstSaturday
END
```

CASE in T-SQL is an expression (like `?:` in C), not a flow control branch like `IF`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the keyword 'End' to the end of the Case statement

```
 DECLARE @FirstSaturday DATETIME
 DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME
 SELECT @FirstSaturday = min(RED1.DATE)
 FROM REDFRIDAYDATES..TBLREDFRIDAYALLDATES RED1
 WHERE Period = 9 
     AND year = 2009

 SELECT @ENDDATE = 
    Case
      WHEN getdate() < @FirstSaturday
      THEN  getdate()
      ELSE  @FirstSaturday 
    End
```